# Передача данных в активный поток python

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня есть поток, который раз в секунду стирает и отрисовывает карту консольной игры. **displayThread = Thread(target=display); displayThread.start()**. Функция display отвечает за отрисовку раз в секунду. Как передать в этот поток координаты игрока(они так же раз в секунду обновляются и находятся в обычном **while True** вне потока)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В принципе нет никаких проблем в передаче координат, если передавать аргумент по ссылке (объект), в общем случае это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
from threading import Thread,Event   
from threading import Event
from time import sleep

class Coord:
    x = 0
    y = 0

def display(event, coord):
    while(True):
        sleep(1)
        if (event.is_set()): break
        print(coord.x, coord.y)

def run():
    event = Event()
    coord = Coord()     
    displayThread = Thread(target=display, args=(event, coord))
    displayThread.start()
    i = 0
    while(True):
        i += 1
        coord.x += 1  # меняем координаты 
        coord.y -= 1
        if (i == 10**7): break 

    event.set()
    displayThread.join()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Вывод примерно такой:

```
2205426 -2205426
4495946 -4495946
6806295 -6806295
9196226 -9196226
```

Comment: Мне это подходит, но можно ли обойтись без event?

Comment: Все, я сам разобрался. Хорошая идея вынести переменные в отдельный класс, ведь раньше они стояли у меня вне функций и классов

Comment: Чем больше глобальных переменных тем хуже производительность, поэтому я стараюсь все что можно оборачивать. И лучше если координаты в данном случае будут меняться в одном месте программы — так будет проще дебажить код, хотя в конкретном случае может это и не важно. Event — это просто способ общения меджу потоками [тут](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-event-modulja-threading/) есть описание других его плюсов, с примерами